# VBA: Message Box Display, Loop on Condition

Tags: vba, loops, conditional-statements, messagebox

I have created VBA code that displays a message box when a certain condition is met. This if statement loops through a determined range. However, the message box is displayed for every cell that meets my condition. Is there a way to ensure the message box is only displayed once?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
For Each cell In Range("S194:BZ194")
    If cell.Value < 0 Then
MsgBox "Unrestricted cash cannot be less than zero (Row 194). Please lower the loan growth rate."
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: exit your for loop if you only want it to display once via the worksheet change event `Exit For`.  Create a global variable to hold a Boolean on if it was shown if you only want to display it once per instance.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement poor man's *data validation*. You're reinventing the wheel, look under the [Data] Ribbon tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For Each cell In Range("S194:BZ194")
        If cell.Value < 0 Then
            MsgBox "Unrestricted cash cannot be less than zero (Row 194). Please lower the loan growth rate."
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```